# Why using built-in methods on list in function change the list but slicing not?

Tags: python, methods, scope, slice

I can not understand this momemt:
we have my_list. We put it in a function to change (function returns nothing).
method pop() change our list.

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3]
def change_list(li):
    li.pop()

change_list(my_list)
print(my_list)
# ans [1, 2]
```

but if change list in function with slicing. It doesn't our list:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3]
def change_list(li):
    li = li[:2]

change_list(my_list)
print(my_list)
# ans [1, 2, 3]
```

how does it work?

I think the methods change the object itself. Slicing return another object but doesn't touch the initial one. But then I assign this new object to the initial variable. Maybe it related to scope?

Comment: The answer is in the question. Read about variable scope.

Comment: and don't use `list` as name - it's a built-in

Comment: @buran although in this case it doesn't really matter... because of scope :)

Comment: @Julien, even in this case, inside the function built-in `list` is shadowed by the parameter/local name `list`. It doesn't cause problem and in many cases it will not, but still - it's a bad habbit and it's worth a word of advise to OP

Comment: `list = ...` at the end of your last function puts the local name `list` on your slice, that's all. The original list is unchanged.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Yes, but I use the same name as a function argument. I thought in this case it will be the reference to the initial object.

Comment: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html All of this is worth reading, but look especially at the example functions "augment_twice" and "augment_twice_bad". These show just the contrast in behaviour that you point out in your question.

Comment: "But then I assign this new object to the initial variable." - this isn't exactly wrong, but it can help to think of it from a different angle. You __re__  -assign the locally-scoped __name__ 'li' to refer to the new object. That name 'li' no longer has any connection to the original object that the function was called with, whereas the globally-scoped name 'my_list' still refers to that original object.

Comment: The answer to your question is simple: `.pop` is a method which mutates the object, slicing is not, because that's what the people who designed the API decided to do.

Comment: "but if change list in function with slicing. " **you don't change the list with slicing**. That is what you must understand. A slice creates *a new list*. Your old list is unaffected by creating a slice. It still exists

Answer (score 0):

It has only marginally to do with the sopes, and more with the difference between altering an object or creating a new object that is derived from the original object.

id(obj) gives you the id of an object, you could also see it as the address the object is stored at. If you now look at what I have done here in the python shell:

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> id(my_list)
140505309164608
>>> id(my_list[:-1])
140505288408512
>>> id(my_list)
140505309164608
>>> my_list.pop()
3
>>> id(my_list)
140505309164608
>>> my_list
[1, 2]
```

... you will see that pop() alters the object my_list is referring to, but not its id, hence my_list[-1:] creates a new object with a different id.
Since the variable in your outer socpe is still set to the id of the original `[1, 2, 3]`, and the assignment inside the function does not alter the original object, the value of the outer variable remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified examples

```
list_a = [1,2,3]
list_b = list_a
```

Now both Variables are pointing to one object.

```
list_a.pop(0)
list_b.pop(0)

#list_a = [3]
#list_b = [3]
```

if you wish to handle a list without this behavior, you can copy the old one

```
list_a = [1,2,3]
list_b = list(list_a) or list_a[:]

list_a.pop(0)

#list_a = [2,3]
#list_b = [1,2,3]
```

edit:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3]
def change_list(li):
   li = li[:2] # <--- in this case li is a new list
```

maybe this is what you're looking for

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3]
def change_list(li):
   return li[:2]

my_list = change_list(my_list)
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all! My misunderstanding was that li = li[:2] create a new local variable and doesn't reference to initial object anymore.

```
>>> my_list = [1,2,3]
>>> id(my_list)
2410656
>>> def change_list(li):
  print(id(li))
  li = li[:2]
  print(id(li))
>>> change_list(my_list)
2410656
2410640
```

Comment: No, the issue **is not that it creates a new local variable**. The issue is that **slicing doesn't mutate the list**.